# Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, upgrade, 20.04, ppa

I'm trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 from Ubuntu 18.04.5.
After `apt update` & `apt upgrade`, I'm trying to

```
do-release-upgrade
```

I get the following  error:

```
    An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 
    This was likely caused by: 
    Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu 
    Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
    package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
    try the upgrade again.
```

I see that I've previously installed `ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` and  `ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi` that cause the issue.

So I try to purge them, but get the following error:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
Updating packages lists
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
root@ubuntu:~# ppa-purge ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
Updating packages lists
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
```

Looks like the purge is failing as the server is no longer available?

How can I remove the packages manually?

**----Edit-----**
/var/log/dist-upgrade/[CURRENT_DATE]/main.log contains the following errors:

```
ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.'
 DEBUG abort called
```

/var/log/dist-upgrade/[CURRENT_DATE]/apt.log contains towards the end

```
Investigating (5) gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 < 3.28.0-1ubuntu1 -> 3.36.0-1ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 Breaks on mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 | 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umH > (< 3.31.4)
  Considering mutter:amd64 2 as a solution to gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 79
  Upgrading mutter:amd64 due to Breaks field in gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64
Investigating (5) mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umU Ib >
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < none | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @un uH >
  Considering gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 0 as a solution to mutter:amd64 2
  MarkKeep mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back mutter:amd64 rather than change gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64
Investigating (5) gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 < none -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @un uN Ib >
Broken gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 Depends on libmutter-6-0:amd64 < none | 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @un uH > (= 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
  Considering libmutter-6-0:amd64 0 as a solution to gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 0
  MarkKeep gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 < none -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @un uN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 rather than change libmutter-6-0:amd64
Investigating (6) gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 < 3.28.0-1ubuntu1 -> 3.36.0-1ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 Breaks on mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 | 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umH > (< 3.31.4)
  Considering mutter:amd64 2 as a solution to gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 79
  Upgrading mutter:amd64 due to Breaks field in gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64
Investigating (6) mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umU Ib >
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < none | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @un uH >
  Considering gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 0 as a solution to mutter:amd64 2
  MarkKeep mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back mutter:amd64 rather than change gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64
Investigating (7) gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 < 3.28.0-1ubuntu1 -> 3.36.0-1ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 Breaks on mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 | 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umH > (< 3.31.4)
  Considering mutter:amd64 2 as a solution to gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 79
  Upgrading mutter:amd64 due to Breaks field in gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64
Investigating (7) mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umU Ib >
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < none | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @un uH >
  Considering gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 0 as a solution to mutter:amd64 2
  MarkKeep mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back mutter:amd64 rather than change gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64
Investigating (8) gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 < 3.28.0-1ubuntu1 -> 3.36.0-1ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 Breaks on mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 | 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umH > (< 3.31.4)
  Considering mutter:amd64 2 as a solution to gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 79
  Upgrading mutter:amd64 due to Breaks field in gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64
Investigating (8) mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umU Ib >
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < none | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @un uH >
  Considering gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 0 as a solution to mutter:amd64 2
  MarkKeep mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back mutter:amd64 rather than change gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64
Investigating (9) gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 < 3.28.0-1ubuntu1 -> 3.36.0-1ubuntu1 @ii umU Ib >
Broken gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 Breaks on mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 | 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umH > (< 3.31.4)
  Considering mutter:amd64 2 as a solution to gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64 79
  Upgrading mutter:amd64 due to Breaks field in gsettings-desktop-schemas:amd64
Investigating (9) mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umU Ib >
Broken mutter:amd64 Depends on gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 < none | 3.36.1-0ubuntu1 @un uH >
  Considering gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64 0 as a solution to mutter:amd64 2
  MarkKeep mutter:amd64 < 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 -> 3.36.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 @ii umU Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back mutter:amd64 rather than change gnome-settings-daemon-common:amd64
Done
```

Thanks!
Vitaliy

Comment: I suspect that you are correct about the reason for failure: A withdrawn or empty PPA will indeed generate a 403 error. Do you recall what you installed from those PPAs? 1) If so, you can remove those packages with ordinary apt. 2) Then you can simply delete the PPA lines from your apt sources using any tool you wish. 3) Finally, since your sources changed, run `sudo apt update`

Comment: Thanks @user535733! Unfortunately I don't recall what exactly I installed via apt, but it looks like I'm stuck with those 2 packages - ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi and ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
How can I find what they correspond to in apt?

Comment: Those are PPA names. PPAs are the *source* that supply packages to you. Package names tend to be much shorter, and do not include `:` or `/`. Call a source a source, and call a package a package. Don't mix them up. Skip 1) until you remember more and move on to 2).

Comment: Thanks @user535733 for pointing the difference! I removed completely all the files under  /etc/apt/sources.list.d which contain any reference to ppa. Still getting the same error, updated the main question with error logs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with doing an upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS.

I had to remove the broken packages listed in `/var/log/dist-upgrade/[CURRENT_DATE]/apt.log`

list broken packages:

```
grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/[CURRENT_DATE]/apt.log
```

Then remove each of those broken packages:

```
apt remove gsettings-desktop-schemas mutter gir1.2-mutter-6
```

It might require removing other packages that depend on those.

Comment: Thanks @Neopallium, is it safe to remove those packages? They look to me system-wide dependent?

Comment: it worked for me.  the `do-release-upgrade` re-installed most of them.  I had to re-install a few applications.  Only had problems with `lightdm` had to switch back to `gdm3` for the login screen.  If you are not using the default login screen `gdm3`, then uninstall your current one and reinstall gdm3.  Check `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` to see if it is set to `/usr/sbin/gdm3`.  You can skip the reboot at the end of the release update and make sure that all your important applications have been re-installed before doing a reboot.

Comment: Also you can just try uninstalling a few of the broken packages and try `do-release-upgrade` again.  It might have only been `mutter` causing the problem.

Comment: it doesn't seem safe to remove gsettings-desktop-schemas

Comment: @Sahin It would only cause a problem if you reboot before running `do-release-upgrade` again.  Then you might be stuck using the terminal login to finish the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

From the answer here: [Upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 prevented by 'E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279062/upgrade-from-18-04-to-20-04-prevented-by-eerror-pkgproblemresolverresolve-g/1340339#1340339)
The problem is not probably related to mutter
try
`sudo apt remove python2.7-minimal` and `sudo apt autoremove`

This actually solved my problem.